# Preserve an external legacy apps file resource fork when including in an Xcode archive

Tags: objective-c, xcode, build-settings, legacy-app

I have created a cocoa application primarily to run on OS 10.6.8. to convert certain types of proprietary legacy files. The app looks at the legacy files creator code and processes it accordingly if it is a known type. Once the file is identified, I call an external legacy app (which I have added to the project) using [NSWorkspace openFile:  withApplication: ]to open the droplet and process the file conversion.

The application works just like it is supposed to until I archive it and try to run it from the application bundle. Actually, it will continue to work but it is using the converter app from the project. If I delete the converter in the project area, then the app in the app bundle can not open the external app in that location. One work around is to delete the external app from the bundle after its archived and replace it with a copy of the one in the project area.

I would appreciate any suggestions on resolving this. I'm not sure if the problem is in some Xcode build setting I can change to include an external apps resource fork when archiving, or if this is a launch services issue with apps hidden in packages, or , something I'm not even considering.

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the "Preserves HFS Data" (COPYING_PRESERVES_HFS_DATA) build setting.

Comment: As it turns out, your suggestion is part of the solution. The other part is to use the entire path name. [[bundle mainBundle]pathForResource], then append the appName to the path string. This apparently tells Launch Services what app it will open rather than hoping LS knows about the app and where it is.